# Join between two master and one detail Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working with Northwind Data Base(Microsoft Example) and i want to know total Sale of each Region.
tables for this example are (Region,Territories,EmployeeTerritories,Employees,Orders and OrderDetails) 
And relations are:

1. Region on to many Territories
2. Territories on to many EmployeeTerritories
3. EmployeeTerritories **many to one** Employees
4. Employees on to many Orders
5. Orders one to many OrderDetails

i know that i should to use Sub query but i dont know how.

```
select
      * 
from
   Region R
   inner join Territories T
       on R.RegionID=T.RegionID
   inner join EmployeeTerritories ET
       on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
   inner join
      (
         select
            E.EmployeeID,
            E.FirstName,
            E.LastName,
            sum(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) as TotalEmployeeSale
          from
             Employees E
             inner join Orders O
                on E.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
             inner join [Order Details] OD
                on o.OrderID=OD.OrderID
             Group by
                E.EmployeeID,
                E.FirstName,
                E.LastName
      )as  ES on ET.EmployeeID=ES.EmployeeID
```

I use this sql query to calculate Total sale for Each Employee but how can i Caclulate is for Each Region.

Comment: Please format the sql so that someone else except you can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't got access to Northwind right now, so this is untested, but you should get the idea...

There's no need to get data about employees if all you want is sales per region. Your subquery is therefore redundant...

```
select
      r.RegionDescription, 
      sum(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)
from
   Region R
   inner join Territories T
       on R.RegionID=T.RegionID
   inner join EmployeeTerritories ET
       on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
   inner join  Employees E
       on ET.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
   inner join Orders O
       on E.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
   inner join [Order Details] OD
                on o.OrderID=OD.OrderID
  Group by r.RegionDescription
```

As discussed in the comments, this "double counts" sales where an employee is assigned to more than one region. In many cases, this is desired behaviour - if you want to know how well a region is doing, you need to know how many sales came from that region, and if an employee is assigned to more than one region, that doesn't affect the region's performance.

However, it means you overstate the sales if you add up all the regions.

There are two strategies to avoid this. One is to assign the sale to just one region; in the comments, you say there's no data on which to make that decision, so you could do it on the "lowest regionID) - something like:

```
select
      r.RegionDescription, 
      sum(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)
from
   Region R
   inner join Territories T
       on R.RegionID=T.RegionID
   inner join EmployeeTerritories ET
       on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
   inner join  Employees E
       on ET.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
   inner join Orders O
       on E.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
   inner join [Order Details] OD
                on o.OrderID=OD.OrderID
  Group by r.RegionDescription
  having et.TerritoryID = min(territoryID)
```

(again, no access to DB, so can't test - but this should filter out duplicates).

Alternatively, you can assign a proportion of the sale to each region - though then rounding may cause the totals not to add up properly. That's a query I'd like to try before posting though!

Comment: No its wrong because EmployeeTerritories  Is a juction table and Eche Territories Have many  Employees  and one Employee in for many Territories . sum(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)
 is Wrong.Some of the Orders Repeat in this join and when you use Sum it calculate the repeated orders

Comment: Ah - okay. Is there a way to allocate an employee to one and only one region? If not, your results would be kinda arbitrary - you could include subquery to get sales for the "earliest" employeeTerritories record, but that may violate the business requirements...

Comment: There is no way to allocate an employee to one region.My Query Calculate Total sale for each Employee.And join this to The employeeTerritories.Problem is here that How can i Sum this Totalsale for Each Region.One TotalSale repeats for each employeeTerritories record in a Region

Comment: I edit your Answer in this way and its work.but know i want to know is my query is true or there is a better way :      i join your query with Region and Territories as a dirived table and count the EmployeeSale foe each Region